# LWC setter is not getting called

Tags: get, set, getter, setter, lwc

LWC setter is not getting called.

```
<template>
 {message}<br><br>1. getter value: {displayMessage}<br><br>2. setter value: {updatedMessage}
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
 
export default class GetterSetter extends LightningElement {
   message;
   updatedMessage ='demo';

   connectedCallback(){
    this.message='2';
   }

   renderedCallback(){
    this.message='3';
   }

   get displayMessage(){
    return this.message;
   }

   set displayMessage(value) {
    this.updatedMessage = value.toUpperCase();
   }
}
```

I have tried [salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/js-props-getters-setters.html).